# Problem deploying vue app on Digitalocean app platform

Tags: vue.js, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

Every time I do a deploy from github to my application on digital ocean I get the following error.

/node_modules/.vite/deps/@iconify_vue.js?v=cfad0217:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 ()

Has anyone had a similar error?